# How to catch named event in Windows CE

Tags: c#, event-handling, windows-ce

In my project, I want to catch some named event from the system, like "IDH/Presence" or "IDH/AmbiantLight".

How can I do that ?

Edit: Is that possible with the EventWaitHandle class of the Smart Device Framework ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the functionality you refer to in the SDF ([ctacke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13154/ctacke) will probably answer that). But, to wait on a named event handle you simple call `CreateEvent` with the name and wait on the handle that is returned.

Be aware that in case the event is auto reset, only one `WaitForSingleObject` call will catch it and then it will be reset so if other threads are waiting on the same handle you might not catch the event.

Comment: It work fine with a while(true) for catch whenever that the named event is raised.
Is there a more elegant way to do this ?

Comment: I didn't get your usage. Can you post code? The elegant way to wait on an event is `WaitForSingleObject`/`WaitForMultipleObjects` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202783.aspx). This is the correct way to work with events, otherwise you miss the whole point of event driven system.

Comment: The same named event can be raised multiple times.
So I have a thread which wait for this event.
Without while(true) only the first event is catched.

Comment: That is the correct way to handle it. However, why do you keep opening and closing the handle> Move the open before the while(true) and the close when you break out of it.

Answer (score 1):

The CF itself doesn't provide the ability to use named system events.

The [SDF's EventWaitHandle](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/4a5cde1e-6842-3cba-297a-36cacba6b3b2.htm) does provide the capability by using either of the constructors that allow for [the name parameter](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/7dd42772-49e1-2f94-444c-b0090ace9b7d.htm).

The other option is to P/Invoke [CreateEvent](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.CreateEvent) and [WaitForSingle](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.WaitForSingleObject)/WaitForMultipleObjects.